# Transferring files through sockets (bir and small sized)

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

Hello I'm trying to implement a server and client couple that can transfer files of any kind and any size but there is a problem I somehow corrupt files. I tried lots of methods but can't figure it out. So basicly I can connect ,I can understand which file does client want, and can send it through sockets. When I try to open that file it shows me an error message(Tried winrar, mp4, avi files) Here is my code:

//Server

```
private void Receive(string receivedFileName, string fileSize)
{
    try
    {
        int receivedBytesLen = 0;
        byte[] incomingFile = new byte[int.Parse(fileSize)];
        activity.AppendText("Preparing to download... \n");
        while (incomingFile != null && int.Parse(fileSize) > receivedBytesLen)
        {
            tempSocket.Receive(incomingFile);

            receivedBytesLen = incomingFile.Length;
            int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(incomingFile, 0);
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileDir + "//" + receivedFileName, incomingFile);
        }
        activity.AppendText("File saved to " + fileDir + "\n");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//server option 2

```
private void Receive(string receivedFileName, string fileSize)
{

try
{

    byte[] incomingFile = new byte[10124 * 5000];
    activity.AppendText("Preparing to download... \n");
    BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath + "//" + receivedFileName, FileMode.Append));
    int receivedBytesLen = tempSocket.Receive(incomingFile, incomingFile.Length, 0);
    int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(incomingFile, 0);
    //string fileName = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(incomingFile, 4, fileNameLen);

    //bWrite.Write(incomingFile, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);
    while (receivedBytesLen > 0)
    {
        receivedBytesLen = tempSocket.Receive(incomingFile, incomingFile.Length, 0);
        if (receivedBytesLen == 0)
        {
            bWrite.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            bWrite.Write(incomingFile, 0, receivedBytesLen);
        }
    }
    activity.AppendText("File saved to " + fileDir + "\n");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//client

```
                private void Upload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//Uploads selected file after clicking upload button.
        try
        {
            if (clientSocket.Connected)
            {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                byte[] sendingFile = null;
                sendingFile = File.ReadAllBytes(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                FileInfo f = new FileInfo(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                string fileSize = f.Length.ToString();
                buffer = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(getUserName.Text + "Upload" + openFileDialog1.SafeFileName + "size" + fileSize + "end");
                clientSocket.Send(buffer);
                activityLog.AppendText("Sending File \n");
                int bytesToBeSent = sendingFile.Length;
                int bytesActuallySent = 0;
                while(bytesActuallySent < bytesToBeSent){
                bytesActuallySent += clientSocket.Send(sendingFile, bytesActuallySent, bytesToBeSent -bytesActuallySent, 0);
                }
                    activityLog.AppendText("File Sent.\n");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Read your code. As it seems, neither of your two server code samples receiving data matches the client code; a-ka the data is sent in a particular order and particular filename-buffer size(s), and the server consumes it in a different order and/or filename-buffer size(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

server option #2 is better. But there are some improvements

1. socket receive buffer is limited decided by OS, generally is 8192
2. use FileStream in client and server and do not forget to close filestream after file download

client:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
byte[] buff = new byte[8192];
do
{
    bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buff, 0, buff.Length);              
    sock.send(dataSock, buff, bytesRead);
}while (bytesRead > 0);
fileStream.close();
```

server:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open)
do
{
    bytesRead = sock.receive(buff, 0, buff.Lenght);
    fileStream.Write(buff, 0, bytesRead );
}while (bytesRead > 0);
fileStream.close();
```

Comment: First of all thank you it solves my problem but in server I can't get out from loop Do you have any suggestions about it ?

Comment: It transfers all the file properly after then it remains in the loop doing nothing.

Comment: when client finish transfers. you should shutdown and close the client socket(if you want to upload next time, create a new socket), then server socket will receive a 0 byte data(bytesRead = 0), jump out the loop. This is a synchronous mode.

Answer (score 0):

In order to satisfy ANY sized file you need an option #3, one that reads a block of bytes til all bytes are received, your option #1 wouldn't do so well on a 3 GIG file running on 2 GIG box...

Here is a link: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

I like option #2 from this link.

However in the example they write to a memoryStream, you should write to a filestream, the target file.